# How can I setup Tomcat running on a virtual machine to enable remote debugging as well as hot swapping synced file changes?

Tags: java, tomcat, virtual-machine

Apologies in advance for the lengthy explanation.

We have an large web application which uses a RabbitMQ server, a Tomcat webserver, a MySQL database, and a Hadoop environment. Most of the team uses Windows, and one uses Ubuntu, but we use CentOS for our deployment environment. We've recently started using vagrant and ansible to standardise environment configuration and deployment across multiple environments. This is part of a move to improve the quality of our application, and helps us to avoid failure between different environments.

We have most of it working now, and over the last few days I've been looking into replicating (or maybe even improving) our current development process with regards to building, running, debugging, and hot-swapping minor code changes without restarting the application. Our existing setup uses embedded Jetty (within eclipse), and we can run Jetty in either Run or Debug mode. With this setup we can place breakpoints, navigate to a relevant page, and when the breakpoint activates we can step through the code, drop frames off the stack to run through a method again, and even make minor changes to the code (within the rules of JVM hotswapping). This is, of course, fantastically helpful for us.

I want to replicate as much of this behaviour as possible except instead of an embedded jetty instance, I want to remote debug the tomcat instance on the virtual machine, but still be able to make changes to the code without needing to restart tomcat each time. I should probably point out at this point that I am aware of JRebel, but it has been deemed unfeasible for our team at this point in time.

At this point in time I have managed to automatically sync (using vagrant); 'src/main/webapp/WEB-INF', 'target/classes' (compiled by eclipse), and 'target/lib' (created by the maven copy-dependencies plugin'. These are all synced to the correct place on the vm, so that tomcat believes it is an exploded war. I have correctly setup Tomcat so that it runs in debug mode, and I have connected to it with eclipse, and successfully entered debug mode by placing a breakpoint. Making any changes to one of the synced files causes tomcat to restart the application and use the new file.

The only problems left are that I lose all my session data when I save a change to a file, and I have to wait for the re-deployment to complete and then repeat appropriate steps to get back to my breakpoint. This is obviously a big waste of time.

So after that lengthy explanation, my questions are:

1. Has anyone managed to achieve what I'm trying to do?
2. Is what I'm trying to do even possible?
3. If so does anyone have any tips to help me finish my configuration?
4. Can I do hot class replacement without triggering a context reload?

Any help would be greatly appreciated and sorry for the essay! :)

Comment: Don't know about Eclipse, but I use NetBeans. I connect to the remote Tomcat instance using the debugger and I can use the "apply code changes" functionality which will cause the JVM Tomcat is running on to reload just the changed classes.

Comment: Jamey, loosing the session and application state is exactly the issue that JRebel addresses. If you're interested, drop me a message, what if we could improve to make it feasible for your environment - I'm involved with development of the product.

Comment: Ah, my apologies. I meant fiscally feasible, I have no doubt it would drop in to our environment very neatly. :)